# <script> tag inside HTML for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, jekyll, liquid

**SPOT the error!**

I have two for loop in html (I am using Jekyll / Liquid), and a `<script>` inside each of them.

I thought that using the code appended below will render a text in the modal image that is equal to the content in `{{member.bio}}`, associated to the `image` and `modal`:

```html
<img id="{{btn_id}}" src="{{member.image}}" alt="" class="is-rounded is-clickable"/>
```

```html
<div id="{{modal_id}}" class="modal">
```

However, it always prints the *first value* of `member.bio` inside the first popup window of the first modal image.

It never enter the second `<script>`

**Note: all `img` and `modal` IDs are unique**

A help would be very appreciated, thank you!

And apologies in advance if the question is trivial, I am quite new to this.

```html
  {% for member_hash in site.data.members %}
  {% assign member = member_hash[1] %}
  <div class="column is-4">
    <div class="content">
      {% assign user_id = {{member.user}} %}
      <var>{% capture btn_id %}btn-{{ user_id }}{% endcapture %}</var>
      <var>{% capture modal_id %}modal-{{ user_id }}{% endcapture %}</var>
      {{btn_id | inspect}}
      {{modal_id | inspect}}

      <center>
        <figure class="image is-128x128">
          <img id="{{btn_id}}" src="{{member.image}}" alt="" class="is-rounded is-clickable"/>
        </figure>
        <div id="{{modal_id}}" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span><p>{{member.bio}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>          
            var js_btn_id = "{{btn_id}}"
            var js_modal_id = "{{modal_id}}"
            document.write(js_btn_id)
            document.write("   ")
            document.write(js_modal_id)
            let btn = document.getElementById(js_btn_id);
            let modal = document.getElementById(js_modal_id);
            let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
            btn.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }
            window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
        </script>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>



  {% for member_hash in site.data.members_second %}
  {% assign member = member_hash[1] %}
  <div class="column is-3">
    <div class="content">
      {% assign user_id = {{member.user}} %}
      <var>{% capture btn_id %}btn-{{ user_id }}{% endcapture %}</var>
      <var>{% capture modal_id %}modal-{{ user_id }}{% endcapture %}</var>
      {{btn_id | inspect}}
      {{modal_id | inspect}}

      <center>
        <figure class="image is-128x128">
          <img id="{{btn_id}}" src="{{member.image}}" alt="" class="is-rounded is-clickable"/>
        </figure>
        <div id="{{modal_id}}" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span><p>{{member.bio}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>          
            var js_btn_id = "{{btn_id}}"
            var js_modal_id = "{{modal_id}}"
            document.write(js_btn_id)
            document.write("   ")
            document.write(js_modal_id)
            let btn = document.getElementById(js_btn_id);
            let modal = document.getElementById(js_modal_id);
            let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
            btn.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }
            window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
        </script>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique

Comment: Check the final html and see if values are duplicated

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! The IDs of each `img` and `modal` should be unique.

Comment: I actually have two `<script>` in the `<html>` code, and it is not entering the second `<script>`, I believe; although it is entering the portion of `<html>` code where the second `<script>` is